# sql получить данные из xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос, sqlce

Есть БД entities.sdf (SQLCe), Отрываю ее через Database.NET Free

В ней таблица Entities в которой данные хранятся в XML

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу получить из этого XML параметр. Пробовал запрос:

```
SELECT CAST ("xml" as XML).value('(/r/name/val)[1]', 'varchar(max)') name 
FROM Entities
WHERE '11905638-b123-47e6-9ba3-f85ddeb40f9c' = Entities.id
```

и запрос

```
select convert(xml, Entities.xml).value('(/r/name/val)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS name 
FROM Entities
WHERE '11905638-b123-47e6-9ba3-f85ddeb40f9c' = Entities.id
```

Оба возвращают ошибку:

```
ErrorCode: -2147467259
[SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider]
HResult: -2147217900, NativeError: 26302
ErrorMessage: The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = XML ]
```

Что можно сделать или что я делаю не так?

Comment: Мне не доводилось общаться с Compact Edition, но по-видимому тип _xml_ компактной редакцией [не поддерживается](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms172424.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выгрузить инсертами и вставить в обычную sql базу, а там уже касты

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/237200)

Comment: Является ответом т.к. Вопрос был Что можно сделать для получения данных. И данное решение помогло их получить